# Stopped the process after executing npm start / macOS homebrew

Tags: npm

I was in the process of creating function components. When I noticed a problem was after I hit save and my terminal never updated me if it was a successful compile... I'll admit I panicked... a little. Then started running npm start and been stuck ever since. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wewFt.png)
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pndi7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was: I performed an `audit --force`.

I didn't understand at the time. Here is an article I found, maybe it can help the next person.
https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/